# Could you please correct me?

Tags: грамматика

- К кому идёт Коля?

  - (Kolia walks to his grand-mother)
  - Коля идёт к бабушке.
- Почему Коля думает, что Соня больна?

  - (Kolia thinks that Sonia is sick because she's going to the hospital)
  - потому что Соня идёт в больницу.
- Почему Соня идёт В Больницу?

  - (Sonia walks to the hospital because her father is a doctor. He works at the hospital).
  - Соня идёт в больницу, потому что её отец врач. Он работает в больнице.
- Куда идут Соня и её папа?

  - (They are going to the cinema.)
  - Соня и её папа/их идут в кино.

And also can you explain me the difference between "кому" and "куда" ?

Comment: Кому means "to whom" and куда means "to where". It'd be hard to mix up those two meanings.

Comment: "Could you please correct me?" don't look like question in Q&A site. May be better to use special site for correections, as http://lang-8.com?

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo. "Doctor" is "врач" in Russian, not *брач*.

As for the difference, these are different pronouns.

*Кому* is a form of "кто" (who). The whole paradigm (Nom-Acc-Gen-Prep-Dat-Inst) is ***кто, кого, кого, (о) ком, кому, кем***

*Куда* is an interrogative adverb "where to?" Similar in meaning or looks are the folowing words:

- *где* = where (location, place of action or being)
- *откуда* = where from (origin, like in "Where are you from?"~"Откуда ты?")
- *туда* = there (direction: *Куда? → Туда*)
- *там* = there (location: *Где? → Там*)
- *тут/здесь* = here (location)
- *сюда* = here (direction: *Come here! = Иди сюда*)

Also, a mistake: They are going to the cinema = ***Они*** идут в кино.